# Using 5 Number Summary on this dataset?

Tags: statistics

Is it a good idea to use the 5-Number Summery on the dataset bellow?

[image]

Or maybe it's better to represent the data using the Mean & Standard Deviation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer may depend on your purposes.  It looks as if your set of $y$-values may come from a bimodal distribution with higher density between $40$ and $60$ than above $80$, and very low density between $60$ and $80$.  One kind of "$5$-number" summary would give the three quartiles and the maximum and the minimum, and to those I would add the sample size to get a $6$-number summary.  But that would fall short of saying what I said about the density above, including its seemingly bimodal nature.

The mean and standard deviation would indicate nothing about the asymmetry (skewness) or bimodality of the distribution.

If the $x$-value is supposed to mean something, then a six-number summary sometimes used would report the $x$- and $y$-means, the $x$-and $y$-standard deviations, the correlation, and the sample size. But it looks as if the $x$-values in your plot may be mere indices, since they look as if they may be perfectly uniformly distributed on a range of integers with only one $y$-value for each $x$-value. It would help if you told us that, and also said something about your purposes in look at this dataset.

Comment: Related: See my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1975680/5-number-summary-vs-mean-and-standard-deviation?rq=1 - perhaps just draw a histogram.

Comment: Can the above distribution be considered symmetric?

Comment: @MATH000 : Does my posted answer address that question? I wrote "higher density between $40$ and $60$ than above $80$", so that rules out symmetry. $\qquad$